# webapp2 self.request.get returns nil

Tags: python, html, forms, google-app-engine, webapp2

I am working on a very simple python program where I present a user a form to choose either Android or IPhone and to enter an email address. The html and the python codes are included below. For whatever reason I am not getting any data from `self.request.get`.

**HTML snippet**

```
 <div id="select_OS">
                <form action="/optin" role="form" class="form-horizontal" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input_contents">
                    <ul id="phone_list" class="list-unstyled">
                        <li><label><input type="radio" class="" name="device" value="android"> Android</label></li>
                        <li><label><input type="radio" class="" name="device" value="iphone"> IPhone</label></li>
                    </ul>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="container">

                        <p class="info_txt_bottom"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></span>
                        Instructions for
                        </p>

                        </<div>

                            <div class="form-group email_content">
                                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-8 col-md-8 enteremail"><input type="email" class="form-control input-lg " id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email" required></div>
                                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-dm-4" ><div class="sentbutton">
                               <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success input-lg colorBlack">Send</button>
                               </div></div>
                            </div>




                </form>
            </div>
```

**Python snippet**

```
class ReadForm(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        logging.warning('The email is %s',self.request.get('email'))
        logging.warning('The device is %s',self.request.get('device'))

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler),
    ('/optin', ReadForm),
], debug=True)
```

Again, the logging only prints “The email is” without including the actual email address that the user enters. The same issue for "The device is". Why is the form data not being passed along?

**UPDATE**

When I do `logging.warning('The REQUEST %s',self.request)`, I get

```
/optin HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Content-Length: 31
Content-Type: text/plain
Content_Length: 31
Content_Type: text/plain
Dnt: 1

…

device=android
email=me@hellothere.com
```

Notice the last two lines. These are the data I have been trying to extract with `self.request.get`, but I keep getting empty back.

Comment: Actually the data is being passed through because if I do `logging.warning('The request is %s',self.request)` I see everything. So it is `self.request.get` that's not working.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that jumps out is the lack of `value=""` attribute on your input field. If you're using html5, that may be a problem, at least according to strict read of the [spec.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-input-element)

Comment: did you see my note where it says that `logging.warning('The request is %s',self.request)` does print out the whole request including the selected device and phone? Thanks.

Comment: Also which line are you referring to? I have `value` defined everywhere.

Comment: I was referring to the html input elements. But no, I didn't see your note.

Comment: oh. try `logging.warning('email is %s' % self.request.get('email'))` (replace the comma with a %)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But no difference. Also, as you might guess, the logging is not the essential part. I leave everything else out because showing the logging section is sufficient. But I am in fact trying to persist this data to datastore and it's blank.

Answer (score 0):

Try `cgi.escape(self.request.get('email'))`, not `self.request.get('email')` same for `device` in the next line and `import cgi` of course

Comment: I tried `cgi.escape`, but of course it made no difference. As I mentioned above, the log is there to help me track. The actual use of the data is for the datastore and the data is not persisted either. `cgi.escape` is for writing to string, so it was a good catch, but it's far from being the problem. The data is there, as I can see it when I print `self.request`. But for whatever reason, doing `self.request.get('emai')` does not return the email value.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your enctype says `enctype="text/plain"`. Simply remove that and it should work. I am not aware of any negative effects of removing enctype. So if someone else here knows a reason that's a bad idea, please share. But basically, once you remove that snippet, your data should come through fine and your log should read

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```